# SSL Vulnerabilities on a personal site

Tags: https, security-certificate

I just managed to install a SSL for my domain hosted on a VPS with CentOS 6.5 (CentOS WEB Panel) and I got it through those "SSL Checker"s online, the most common errors are below:

- > This server supports anonymous (insecure) suites (see below for details).
- > This server supports weak Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange parameters.
- > This server accepts RC4 cipher, but only with older protocol versions.
- > The server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers.
- > A lot of "Cipher Vulnerabilities".

Is this going to affect my small website? Do I need to fix those or can I live well with them?

Edit:
By small website I mean a new site wich is not intented for a big audience, say under 80 views per day.

About the vulerabilities above, I'm asking you if I should bother to fix them.

I am not running an e-commerce or a website that truly requires SSL, just a blog and I bought a SSL because it was at promo and because I wanted to learn how to install them.

So, the errors above are going to make my SSL fail and display a "broken https" because if not, I don't really need to fix them, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Sorry but your question is too broad because you have listed far to many SSL Vulnerabilities within one question and would require a full tutorial for each issue. I recommend that you post a question for each of the vulnerabilities, but do check for duplicates before posting as this is also another closure reason.

Comment: Also, it will be good if you can describe the "Small Website" term. What type of website is yours and what data you are handling on it.

Comment: Additionally you will need to provide much more information in regards of your server side software and so forth. If you unsure of the server-side software then the chances are you are using shared hosting. If you are using shared hosting none of the issues you have listed can be resolved by yourself in any case and you would need to contact them.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't know how to explain it better (after the edit), I am just trying to understand those errors because I couldn't found much info online.